# Lambda takes iterator as parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, iterator

How to create a `lambda` function that accepts `iterators` for `vector`,`list`,`array`?
Something like:

```
auto do_somthing=[](iterator beg,iterator end){
    //code here
}
```

Comment: Just write it. Could you provide some more context, please?

Comment: How can I do it? I can not just declare parameter as iterator?

Comment: I mean what ever is inside assume there is std::sort(beg,end)

Comment: Why not? Choose the right iterator type and you're fine. Do you get any error message or something?

Comment: You're not going to have such luck with C++11. It was C++14 that added this capability for completely generic parameters, and C++17 will probably allow your usage, letting you do `RandomAccessIterator beg` to mean anything satisfying the `RandomAccessIterator` concept. Note that `std::sort` doesn't work with `std::list` iterators like you wanted in the question.

Comment: @chris So in C++11 I have to use a normal templated function instead? no other solution?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, I don't see any way to take advantage of lambda syntax in C++11 with generic parameters.

Comment: @chris Thanks.. got  it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@rollbear answered this for C++14, using a generic lambda. In C++11, you can hand-code such a "generic lambda:"

```
struct GenericLambda
{
  template <class It>
  void operator() (It beg, It end) { /*:::*/ }
} do_something;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use C++14, generalized lambdas will solve your problem nicely.

```
auto do_something = [](auto begin, auto end) {
   // code here
};

int x[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
do_something(std::begin(x), std::end(x));
std::set<int> s{3, 4, 12, 55, 98 };
do_something(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
```

Comment: That is great! However, I am stick to C++11

Comment: @HumamHelfawi then I fear you do not have much to hope for, alas.

Answer (score 2):

If you're limited to c++11, and you need the generic lambda because you're in a templated function where the container is a template argument, then you can get the iterator type like this:

```
template<class T>
void foo()
{
    using iterator = typename T::iterator;
    auto lambda = [](iterator beg,iterator end){}
}
```

Comment: Nice way. However, this is not my case. I am in a non-templated function but need to use templated lambda